# Node js environment variable for localAddress

Tags: node.js

Is there any environment variable for Net [localAddress](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_connect_options_connectlistener), somehow similar to NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED ? I use many node modules that connect to external services via socket/http and those modules does not provide option to set localAddress.

If such a variable does not exists, any idea/workaround will be appreciate. Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean local address on external services, you may have remote address, please clarify

Comment: I mean the local address the socket should connect from [see here](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_connect_options_connectlistener)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't such an environment variable.

As a workaround, you could monkeypatch `net.Socket#connect` when a particular environment variable exists, and use it as local address:

```
const net = require('net');

if (process.env.LOCAL_ADDRESS) {
  const connect = net.Socket.prototype.connect;

  net.Socket.prototype.connect = function(options) {
    if (! options.localAddress) {
      options.localAddress = process.env.LOCAL_ADDRESS;
    }
    return connect.apply(this, arguments);
  };
}
```

To use:

```
$ env LOCAL_ADDRESS=xx.xx.xx.xx node your-script.js
```

This should be loaded somewhere early on in your code, and only works for modules that (eventually) use `net.Socket#connect`, which may rule out native modules that set up connections themselves (like some database drivers).

To also catch those, you need to resort to an external solution like [`libsis`](https://www.palfrader.org/code/libsis/) (which I've never used myself, so can't say if it actually works).